# stop at the first string matched using strpos() in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

This maybe some simple silly thing but I can't figure it out on my own.

I am trying to make a mobile detection script and have had great success. But upon deeper inspection I found that one of my `IF` clauses seems to be returning `TRUE` but with the wrong match.

I have this array:

```
private $arrAgent = array(
    'sony',
    'symbian',
    'nokia',
    'samsung',
    'mobile',
    'windows ce',
    'blackberry',
    'ericsson',
    'danger',
    'palm',
    'series60',
    'palmsource',
    'pocketpc',
    'smartphone',
    'vodafone',
    'iphone',
    'ipad',
    'android'
    );
```

then I have a function that will loop the array and find if it matches

```
private function detectMobileAgent() {

    if ($this->MobileDevice === false) {

        foreach ($this->arrAgent as $key => $value) {

            if (strpos(Server::userAgent(), $value) !== false) {
                $this->MobileDevice = true;
                // echo $value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I found an error in the iPad/iPhone userAgent that prevents from me getting a clear reading.

The iPad user agent looks like this:

```
mozilla/5.0 (ipad; u; cpu os 4_3_2 like mac os x; en-us) applewebkit/533.17.9 (khtml, like gecko) version/5.0.2 mobile/8h7 safari/6533.18.5
```

I got that from a iOS simulator that comes with xCode, on my actual iPad I saw an almost identical user agent, just the OS version and safari version were different.

Now my problem is that in that user agent, the string position returns a match for `ipad` AND `mobile`, how can I get it to stop after the first string matched?

Comment: By "stop it" you mean to get the leftmost string match?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: ya, but as John Flatness point out, that since I have the term mobile before my ipad, then the loop will break after finding the first match.

Comment: Wait a second, an iPad is not in your list of mobile devices, so "ipad" will never match. Only "mobile" will match. Perhaps your bug is assuming that "mobile" actually means "a mobile device with a 3.5 inch display"?

Comment: @Abhi: typo on my part. My original list has about 100 devices and for the sake of readability i watered it down and on accident deleted the ipad entry. thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Josept Silber: i didn't know such an initiative existed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will already stop at the first string in `$arrAgent` that matches; that's what the `break` inside the loop is doing.

If you want to prioritize a match against `ipad` over one against `mobile`, just rearrange your `$arrAgent` so `'ipad'` appears before `'mobile'`.

If you make sure the array is arranged with specific terms at the beginning and generic terms at the end, you'll always get the most specific possible match returned.

Comment: hmmm, i put the break in there for that reason but geez your right! I forgot that the iteration is dumb in that sense haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of experimentation with this, and the best approach of all the techniques I tried is to use regex:

```
$arrAgent = array(
  'sony',
  'symbian',
  'nokia',
  'samsung',
  'mobile',
  'windows ce',
  'blackberry',
  'ericsson',
  'danger',
  'palm',
  'series60',
  'palmsource',
  'pocketpc',
  'smartphone',
  'vodafone',
  'iphone',
  'android',
  'ipad'
);

$agent = 'mozilla/5.0 (ipad; u; cpu os 4_3_2 like mac os x; en-us) applewebkit/533.17.9 (khtml, like gecko) version/5.0.2 mobile/8h7 safari/6533.18.5';

$pattern = '/((' . implode(')|(', $arrAgent) . '))/';

$found = preg_match($pattern, $agent, $matches);
if (!$found) {
  print 'not a mobile device';
  exit;
}

print 'device: ' . $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply first check if it's an iPad?

Something like this:

```
if ($this->MobileDevice === false && strpos(Server::userAgent(), 'ipad') === false) {

    foreach ($this->arrAgent as $key => $value) {

        if (strpos(Server::userAgent(), $value) !== false) {
            $this->MobileDevice = true;
            // echo $value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because i am not making an iOS mobile detection but for androids and misc mobile devices too. so the detection has to be generic in that sense.

Comment: I'm not following you: if it's not an iOS device, `strpos(Server::userAgent(), 'ipad') === false` will always be true, so that it'll then loop through your array as usual.